# PCA in R with prcomp

Tags: r

I am trying to compute an index with PCA. I am using 'mtcars' as my dataset. This is my code:

```
 pca_mt<- prcomp(mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)], center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)
```

How do I get the weights for each variable to sum them up to compute an index?
Appreciate if someone can explain about what
`pca_mt$rotation`  , `pca_mt$x` are.

Comment: Take a look at [prcomp](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/prcomp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps you to understand better what `pca_mt$rotation`, `pca_mt$x` are:

```
data <- mtcars[,c(1:7,10,11)]
pca_mt<- prcomp(data, center = F,scale. = F)
sum(data[1,] * pca_mt$rotation[,1]) == pca_mt$x[1,1]
[1] TRUE
```

Note that this only works because `center=F` and `scale.=F`.

For further reading, I recommend https://builtin.com/data-science/step-step-explanation-principal-component-analysis to get a first idea of what PCA is.

So, to get to know how much variance can be explained with the PCA components, you can use

```
summary(pca_mt)
Importance of components:
                            PC1      PC2      PC3     PC4     PC5     PC6    PC7    PC8    PC9
Standard deviation     310.1169 40.88309 15.83774 2.12821 0.99854 0.74271 0.4412 0.2913 0.2168
Proportion of Variance   0.9803  0.01704  0.00256 0.00005 0.00001 0.00001 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
Cumulative Proportion    0.9803  0.99738  0.99993 0.99998 0.99999 1.00000 1.0000 1.0000 1.0000
```

The first component explaines 98,03% of variance in the data, the next one (98,03%-99,738%) and so on. So, using the first component you can explain almost all of the variance in your data.

Comment: I see. Since PC1 explains 98.03%, I can pca_mt$rotation of PC1 as my weights right? I have read from a site that the square of rotation is the weight. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "weights". Do you want to generate an index saying which variable is most important for/within PC1? I guess, then you can square the rotation[,1] (I assume center=T, scale=T should be set in your analysis then to avoid scale issues).

Comment: I am trying to find a weight so I can multiply with my raw data set and sum them up into an index. But I have seen other comment that we should choose PC1 from pca_mt$x as the index